# Spark IllegalArgumentException: Column features must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I'm trying to use the `org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression` fit my data. So I've got the original RDD transformed to *dataframe*, and have tried to feed it to the *linearRegression* model.

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate
val parsedData = dataRDD.map{
  item =>
    val doubleArray = Array(item._1.toDouble, item._2.toDouble, item._3.toDouble)
    val features = Vectors.dense(doubleArray)
    Row(item._4.toDouble, features)
}

val schema = List(
  StructField("label", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("features", new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT, true)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  parsedData,
  StructType(schema)
)
val lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val lr_model = lr.fit(df)
```

And here is what the dataframe looks like:

```
+---------+-------------+
|    label|     features|
+---------+-------------+
|      5.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|     20.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|    689.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|    627.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|    127.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|     76.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      5.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      2.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|    329.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|2354115.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|      5.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|   4303.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
+---------+-------------+
```

But it presented the error below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.
```

The later data type doesn't seem to be different from the one required. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression` (sparkML) with the old version of `VectorUDT` (mllib which is deprecated) and they do not seem to work together.

Replace `new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` by `new org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` and it should work.

Note that to avoid declaring the schema, you can create the dataframe with `toDF` (after importing spark's implicits) to let Spark infer the right type (`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT`) for you:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import spark.implicits._
val df = dataRDD.map{ item =>
    val doubleArray = Array(item._1.toDouble, item._2.toDouble, item._3.toDouble)
    val features = Vectors.dense(doubleArray)
    (item._4.toDouble, features)
}.toDF("label", "features")
```